# Define only one struct and have it process all the inner elements of a XML file in Go?

Tags: xml, struct, go, unmarshalling

Suppose I have the following xml:

```
<main symbol="X">
<blockA main_score="3">
    <a score="0"/>
</blockA>
<blockB>
    <b id="3" name="Mike"/>
</blockB>
</main>
```

And I'd like to define the following struct (blank tags are parts I want to solve):

```
type Result struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"main"`
    Symbol string `xml:"symbol,attr"`
    MainScore int
    Score int
    Id int
    Name string
}
```

And what I'd like to get is the following struct:

```
symbol: X
main_score: 3
score: 0
id: 3
name: Mike
```

So how can I define XML tags that goes into inner elements (`blockA`, `blockB`) and also reaches its attribute values (`main_score`) and inner elements (`score`, `id`, `name`)?

I can address the issue here by defining yet another structs and embedding them within the parent `Result` struct. However, is it still feasible to NOT use the embedding struct and just define struct tags within the main struct and have it process the whole elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is currently possible to unmarshal that XML into your structure with the current version of the package.

If it was supported, you'd want to annotate `MainScore` with:

```
MainScore int `xml:"blockA>main_score,attr"`
```

i.e. pick the `main_score` attribute from the `blockA` sub-element.  This does not currently work though, as described in [issue 3688](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3688).

At the moment, I think you will need to create nested structs to fully unmarshal the data you're after.

Comment: Yup, it's exactly what I first attempted to define, but wasn't able to work with it. So I'll define with nested structs and work with them. Thanks your answer though.